# Improving a loops and tasks to scrape multiple paths that I need to match values

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, cheerio

The page elements are in this pattern:

```
<ul class="scorer-info">
 <li class="  ">
   <span class="scorer">
       <a href="/players/maximilian-mittelstadt/359295/">
         M. Mittelstädt
       </a>

       

         <span class="minute">
           3'
         </span>

       

         <span class="assist">
           (assist by
           <a href="/players/salomon-kalou/2540/">S. Kalou</a>)
         </span>

   </span>

   <span class="score">1 - 0</span>

   <span class="scorer">
  </span>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </li>
 <li class="  ">
   <span class="scorer">
   </span>

   <span class="score">1 - 1</span>

   <span class="scorer">

         <span class="minute">
           7'
         </span>


       <a href="/players/serge--gnabry/213651/">
         S. Gnabry
       </a>

       

  </span>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </li>
 <li class="  ">
   <span class="scorer">
   </span>

   <span class="score">1 - 2</span>

   <span class="scorer">

         <span class="minute">
           49'
         </span>


       <a href="/players/serge--gnabry/213651/">
         S. Gnabry
       </a>

       

         <span class="assist">
           (assist by
           <a href="/players/james-david-rodriguez/72408/">J. Rodríguez</a>)
         </span>
  </span>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </li>
 <li class="  ">
   <span class="scorer">
       <a href="/players/davie-selke/213931/">
         D. Selke
       </a>

       

         <span class="minute">
           67'
         </span>

       


   </span>

   <span class="score">2 - 2</span>

   <span class="scorer">
  </span>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </li>
 <li class="  ">
   <span class="scorer">
   </span>

   <span class="score">2 - 3</span>

   <span class="scorer">

         <span class="minute">
           98'
         </span>


       <a href="/players/kingsley-coman/265385/">
         K. Coman
       </a>

       

         <span class="assist">
           (assist by
           <a href="/players/robert-lewandowski/41310/">R. Lewandowski</a>)
         </span>
  </span>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

The values that are collected by the patches if i need are:

| span.minute | span.score |
| --- | --- |
| 3' | 1 - 0 |
| 7' | 1 - 1 |
| 49' | 1 - 2 |
| 67' | 2 - 2 |
| 98' | 2 - 3 |

Every `span.minute` contains a `span.score` and I want to find the last `span.score` that `span.minute` is less than or equal to `90`. In this example, the last one is `67` → `2-2`

My Code:

```
function score() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('copy');
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('URL URL URL URL', {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 404) {
  } else {
    var contentText = response.getContentText();
    var $ = Cheerio.load(contentText);
    
    var list_minutes = [];
    var list_score = [];

    var minute_goal = $('ul.scorer-info > li > span.scorer > span.minute');
    var score_goal = $('ul.scorer-info > li > span.score');

    minute_goal.each((index, element) => {list_minutes.push([($(element).text().trim()).substring(0, ($(element).text().trim()).indexOf("'"))]);});
    score_goal.each((index, element) => {list_score.push([($(element).text().trim()).replace(/ /g,'')]);});

    var before_90 = '0-0';

    var i=0;
    var max = list_minutes.length
    for(i; i<max; i++){
      if (list_minutes[i][0] <= 90) {
        before_90 = list_score[i][0];
      }
    }
    Logger.log(before_90)
  }
}
```

Output `Logger.log`:

```
2-2
```

As seen, this way I need to create several lists until I can in a last loop to find the last value of the list before the `90'`.

Is there an improved way to reduce this amount of tasks and at least generate a single loop between paths to reduce the code size and its execution time?

Comment: In your sample HTML, do you want to retrieve the value of `2-2`? If my understanding is correct, I cannot understand the logic for retrieving `2-2`. Can I ask you about the detailed logic for retrieving it?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike every ```span.minute``` contains a ```span.score``` and I want to find the last ```span.score``` that ```span.minute``` is less than or equal to ```90```. In this example, the last one is ```67``` → ```2-2```!

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to retrieve your expected value, how about the following modification?

#### From

```
var list_minutes = [];
var list_score = [];

var minute_goal = $('ul.scorer-info > li > span.scorer > span.minute');
var score_goal = $('ul.scorer-info > li > span.score');

minute_goal.each((index, element) => {list_minutes.push([($(element).text().trim()).substring(0, ($(element).text().trim()).indexOf("'"))]);});
score_goal.each((index, element) => {list_score.push([($(element).text().trim()).replace(/ /g,'')]);});

var before_90 = '0-0';

var i=0;
var max = list_minutes.length
for(i; i<max; i++){
  if (list_minutes[i][0] <= 90) {
    before_90 = list_score[i][0];
  }
}
Logger.log(before_90)
```

#### To:

```
var minute_goal = $('ul.scorer-info > li > span.scorer > span.minute').toArray();
var score_goal = $('ul.scorer-info > li > span.score').toArray();
var res = minute_goal.reduce((ar, e, i) => {
  var n = parseInt($(e).text(), 10);
  if (n <= 90) ar.push([n, $(score_goal[i]).text().trim().replace(/ /g, '')]);
  return ar;
}, []).pop();
console.log(res) // [ 67, '2-2' ]
```

- When this modified script is run for your showing HTML data, you can see the value of `[ 67, '2-2' ]` at the log.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the execution time for yours is really an issue but this is what I would do:

```
// get the last minute span that's less than 90
let minuteSpan = $('.minute').get().filter(s => Number($(s).text().replace("'", '')) < 90).pop()
// get the score sibling
let scoreSpan = $(minuteSpan).closest('li').find('.score')

console.log($(minuteSpan).text(), $(scoreSpan).text())
```